# Is FormData object required with Vuejs to upload file to laravel backend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Is the **FormData** object absolutely necessary to work with files and to upload them to my backend made with laravel?

Secondly, would it be a good practice to wrap all form inputs in a FormData object, even non file input?

Currently I try this

```
<input type="file" @change="onVideoSelected" name="explenationVideo">
```

My method logic:

```
onVideoSelected(event) {
    this.form.video = event.target.files[0];
}
```

My data structure

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            name : '',
            contentType : 'video',
            imageGroup : [],
            video : null,
            difficulty : '',
        }
    }
}
```

And when I submit

```
axios.post('/backoffice/exercises', this.form)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        this.messages.push('Exercice ajouté!');
                    });
```

But when I try to view the detail in the backend like

```
dd($request->file('video'));
```

I have a **null** value.